# How to change error reporting level in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to learn the laravel 5. But it is difficult to figure out where the error is happening due to laravel error reporting something like this.

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
FatalErrorException in 4f9b115a4a5a24f50d7dbdbe2511472f line 28:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'
in 4f9b115a4a5a24f50d7dbdbe2511472f line 28
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '4', 'message' => 'syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'', 'file' => '/opt/lampp/htdocs/first-project/storage/framework/views/4f9b115a4a5a24f50d7dbdbe2511472f', 'line' => '28')) in compiled.php line 1721
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

So, I like to change the error reporting to php  but I did not get any idea how to do that.

I had tried some method like changing APP_DEBUG=false to APP_DEBUG=true in .env but it didn't work

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Exceptions

Comment: Even though it doesn't look nice, the error message shows you even the line where your error is. Just open the file described, scroll down  to line 28 and fix it in your original file. You'll find the file stated in the message in your storage/framework/views folder

Comment: Thanks man for the reply ..problem is solved

Answer (score -2):

The file `4f9b115a4a5a24f50d7dbdbe2511472f` is just a view .blade.php but compiled. Just go to the file, when you know what view is, go to that view and correct the error.